# E-mail notification based on cell value. Unable to apply script function for all rows

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using Google sheets and the Google script editor to create a script to automatically send myself an e-mail every time a product quantity goes below the minimum inventory level. Since I have multiple products with different minimum inventory levels I expect to get a series of e-mails, one for each row.

I use one sheet for the actual Inventory data and another sheet that contains information for the script to refer to, such as my email and what message to include in the e-mail.

I succeeded having an e-mail sent collecting data from the first row of the Inventory sheet but I am not being able to apply that for all the following rows.
I tried changing the `.getRange("F2")` to `.getRange("F2:F")`, then whenever one of the products goes under the minimum inventory level I get one single e-mail  containing the information about all products, regardless of whether their quantity is under the minimum level or not.

The ideal solution would be ONE single e-mail containing all the information about all products that are under the minimum quantity .

Here is a link to my spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZHmBvi8ZeaDRYq6Qigaw08NUiOwZumPrLnvnka_mgmA/edit?usp=sharing

Current script:

```
function CheckInventory() {
  // Fetch inventory quantity
  var InventoryRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Inventory").getRange("F2"); 
  var Inventory = InventoryRange.getValue();

   // Fetch minimum quantity
  var MinimumQuantityRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Inventory").getRange("D2");
  var MinimumQuantity = MinimumQuantityRange.getValue();

  // Check Inventory
  if (Inventory < MinimumQuantity){
    // Fetch email address
    var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Notification Rules").getRange("E2");
    var emailAddress = emailRange.getValues();

    // Fetch email message details.
    var detailsRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Notification Rules").getRange("G2");
    var details = detailsRange.getValues();
    var subjectdetailsRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Notification Rules").getRange("H2");
    var subjectdetails = subjectdetailsRange.getValues(); 

    // Send Alert Email.
    var message = details;
    var subject = subjectdetails;
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you want to send multiple emails, you'd have to create a loop to check each value & send an email based on it.

Comment: Ideally it could one be one single e-mail containing all products that have inventory numbers lower than minimum levels.

Comment: Since you want one single e-mail to be sent, I assume that the e-mail address is always the same.

Comment: The same for subject. You cannot have many subjects in one e-mail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Update:

- As you said in a comment, you want the email to be sent when you edit an inventory cell, and only if this edited inventory quantity is below the corresponding minimum. So here I update my answer accordingly.

First, I guess you have done this already, but because the function uses `sendEmail`, you will have to [grant authorization](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#restrictions) for it to work. I created a trigger for that. Run this once:

```
function createEditTrigger() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("CheckInventory")
    .forSpreadsheet(ss)
    .onEdit()
    .create();
}
```

Then, this is the function that will run every time the spreadsheet is edited. To avoid the email to be sent every time the file is edited, we need a condition that checks whether the edited cell is an inventory and that this inventory is below the minimum:

```
function CheckInventory(e) {
  var ss = e.source;
  var inventorySheet = ss.getSheetByName("Inventory");
  var rowIndex = e.range.getRow();
  var columnIndex = e.range.getColumn();
  var numCols = 6;
  var row = inventorySheet.getRange(rowIndex, 1, 1, numCols).getValues()[0];
  var editedInventory = row[5];
  var editedMinimum = row[3];
  var sheetName = ss.getActiveSheet().getName();
  // Checking that: (1) edited cell is an inventory quantity, and (2) Inventory is below minimum
  if(editedInventory <= editedMinimum && sheetName == "Inventory" && columnIndex == 6 && rowIndex > 1) {
    var inventoryValues = inventorySheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    var emailBody = "";
    for(var i = 1; i < inventoryValues.length; i++) {
      var inventory = inventoryValues[i][5];
      var minimum = inventoryValues[i][3];
      if(inventory <= minimum) {
        var productName = inventoryValues[i][0] + " " + inventoryValues[i][1];
        var productUnits = minimum + " " + inventoryValues[i][4];
        var messagePart1 = "Inventory for " + productName + " has gone under " + productUnits + ". ";
        var messagePart2 = "Organise purchase order. Inventory as of today is: " + inventory + " " + inventoryValues[i][4];
        var message = messagePart1.concat(messagePart2);
        var newItem = "<p>".concat(message, "</p>");
        emailBody += newItem;
      }
    }
    var emailSubject = "Low inventory alert";
    var emailAddress = "your-email@your-domain.com";
    // Send Alert Email
    if(emailBody != "") {
      MailApp.sendEmail({
        to: emailAddress,
        subject: emailSubject,
        htmlBody: emailBody
      });  
    }
  }
}
```

As I said in a comment, if you just want to send an email, it doesn't make sense to have many email subjects, so I hardcoded the subject.

Regarding the emails, I assumed you just want an email address to receive the email, so I hardcoded it too. If you want all the different email addresses found in Notifications tab to receive emails regarding all products, a small fix would be needed to this code. Tell me if that's needed for you.

Also, I didn't use your notifications tab at all, I created the message directly using the script. I'm not sure it is that useful to have the sheet "Notification Rules". Much of its info is the same as the one in inventory, and the rest of data (email address, basically) could be easily included there. But whatever suits you.

I hope this is of any help.

Comment: This works perfectly and hardcoding the details indeed makes more sense in this case. Thank you for that!

Comment: You're welcome. Also, remember that in order to mark your question as solved you can accept the answer that provided a solution to your problem.

Comment: Sure I will do that, however I'm not being able to create a trigger that runs the code ONLY when a cell is edited and that cell's products quantity goes under the minimum.
I have been able to trigger it when the spreadsheet is edited, but that activates the trigger regardless of whether the cell being edited has the product's quantity under minimum or not. So if any other cells have the  quantity under minimum, an e-mail is sent. This is not practical since the spreadsheet is being edited on a daily basis.
Is there a way to do this adjusting the trigger only or the code has to be remodeled?

Comment: Do you want to send data of the product that is being edited only or of all products that are below minimum?

Comment: @DanielG., I did update my answer based on your comments. Was your issue solved? Remember that if you want to mark your question as solved you should accept whatever answer provided a solution to your problem. If that's not the case and your issue is not solved, consider explaining why that's not the case so that this community can help you.

Comment: @lamblichus apologies for the late reply and my sincere thanks for the updated code! It works perfectly now if the spreadsheet is edited directly but the inventory quantity values are actually being imported from another spreadsheet. So when that spreadsheet is edited the change takes place on the current one. However the email is not sent given that this spreadsheet was not directly edited. Am I looking at a complex scenario or just a small tweak of codes would fix that?

Comment: If the output is coming from a formula change, but the formula itself doesn't, the edit trigger will not fire. So in this case, the trigger should be listening to changes in the spreadsheet that is actually edited (the one where values are being imported from). And of course, the condition to send the email should change (it should reference the cells in the original spreadsheet). All in all, it would probably take a bit more than a small tweak. I'd recommend you to create another question with this.

Comment: Also, you should share a sanitized copy of the edited spreadsheet if you want people to help you with that.

Comment: @lamblichus I will rework my system and apply the script directly to the spreadsheet being edited to simplify things. Thanks again for all the support!